# Where should I install my Continuous Integration Server?

Tags: continuous-integration

I'm the lead developer at a startup and we currently have the following setup:

```
- Development Server
- Staging Server
- Production Server
- Paid Subversion Hosting

- My local machine
- 2 other developers' local machines
```

Where is the best place to host the CI server? On an entire new server? Or is my local machine sufficient for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally not local machine (when other options are available) as you mostly want to have the same "stuff" installed (or not installed) on the build server as you have on the production server, so that whatever is running on the the build server is running in as realistic a scenario as possible.

Speaking from a .NET point of view, this means that I don't want (for example) Visual Studio running on the build server, ruling out my local machine.

It would also be a good idea to be sure someone on your team has access to the machine and can perform actions on it, thus potentially ruling out the hosted solution.

Aside from that, as long as it's on a box with a half decent spec, I don't think it really matters.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely not your local machine.  I'd suggest a separate server unless you don't mind slowing down your dev server.

I say not your local machine because the last thing you want to be hindered by is builds.  Nothing is more frustrating than a slow machine.  And you should generally keep official builds generated off of a separate server.

Answer (score 1):

I would put it at the development server, staging server, or the paid subversion hosting instance, if possible.